# Which one is correct? "it will help me address the issue" or it will help me to address"?

Tags: phrases, to-infinitive

Which one of these two phrases is correct?

> it will help me **address** the issue

or

> it will help me **to address** the issue

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

We can use 'help' with an object and an infinitive with **to**.

Can you help me to find my key? He is helping me to clean the room. Let me help you to carry the bag. I helped her to choose some new clothes.

We can also use the infinitive without to.(in an informal style)

Can you help me find my key? He is helping me clean the room. Let me help you carry the bag. I helped her choose some new clothes.